# Why different Design between Material Design & Angular Material

Tags: angular-material, material-design

I am working on an Angular Application with Angular material. I noticed that there are subtle differences between the two. Especially in the inputs. Is that on purpose? Can I get them the same by some Configuration? Here one example what I mean.

[image]  vs  [image]

- Paddings & Margins are different
- MD has a border radius that AM not has

I know it doesn't seem much, but i would really like to get the look equal.

Comment: What you are looking at are just various [form field appearance variants](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#form-field-appearance-variants) as described in the docs. How I understand it, Material Design is just a spec and Angular Material an implementation of it.
The field on the left has the `fill` appearance and the one on the right either the `standard` or `legacy` appearance, hard to tell.